# htaccess, no variable go to allcategories.php

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

I have the htaccess rule above:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ category.php?categoria=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?categoria=$1&id=1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/ allcategories.php
```

So if I have `category/some_name` or `category/some_name/id` it will redirect to category.php.

If I have only `category/`to allcategories.php.

The problem is urls like this:

```
category/j.j._name
category/victoria%27s_secret
```

It has a value (j.j...) and it is redirecting to allcategories.php instead of category.php. What is wrong? is it the special characters? how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak your regex to allow special characters:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ category.php?categoria=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?categoria=$1&id=1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/?$ allcategories.php [L,NC]
```

`[^/]` will match anything except a `/`.